# Is it possible to open word document from website and save it like access from local network?

Tags: ms-office

I need to create some website that allow user to edit Microsoft office document like Microsoft word. User can open document from this website after that user can save changed document to website like user open it from network location ("//Server-Name/path/document.docx")

**Update**

I try to use ftp server for containing documents. After that, I open document from web browser or windows explorer. Next, Microsoft Word opens my document but Word can't save it to original location on ftp server. Because Word always open document from temporary folder and it suggests me to save document to another location. However, if I directly open document from Word, Word will upload file to ftp server when I save document.

Do you have any idea for direct opening document by Word without using ActiveX?

**Thanks,**

Comment: This is what is done in Google Docs.

Comment: I think this problem can be solved by some technology like ftp or file sharing. But I don't sure about how to sync user account between this service and my webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at

[Google Documents List Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/overview.html)

Comment: I don't like online document editor. However, It doesn't answer my main question about how to immediately save changed document to website without uploading document by user like open document from local network.